# React native run-ios run-android entry file

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I know that in `react-native bundle` command you can bundle your application with a specified entry file using the `--entry-file` flag. Is there a similar flag or workaround for `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android` command where you can specify an entry file?

Comment: you can simply import your file in both of these files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-native run-android --help` reveals some options but none to specify the entry point. However in `android/app/build.gradle` you will find:

```
project.ext.react = [
    bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
    entryFile: "index.android.js",
    bundleInRelease: true,
    jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
    resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release"
]
```

You can then create different variants in the gradle build

```
buildTypes {
    customVariant {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        renderscriptDebuggable false
        zipAlignEnabled true
        project.ext.react.entryFile "custom.android.js" 
    }
}
```

and would then be able to do `react-native run-android --variant=customVariant`